# in XE5 everytime I make a project it recompile everything

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe5

Does anyone know how to setup the make option to stop recompiling everything every time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for C++Builder or Delphi? And XE5 is not a Borland product, it is an Embarcadero product. Borland sold off its development tools several years ago, it is not involved in them anymore.

Comment: Sure: you just have to fix your makefile so that it doesn't rebuild everything every time.  Simple!

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes it is Embacadero's products

Comment: @MadScientist it turns out something similar to what you suggest. In XE5 everytime you have a make command, the compiler will look at the file called builtins.mak. It turns out my XE5 doesn't have the file and I copy the file from the old borland builder6 and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is rebuilding everything, then chances are that either something deep down in the project really is changing every time, or maybe you have library .pas files on your project's search path that are preventing the compiler from using compiled .dcu files correctly.  Typically the compiler only recompiles a unit if it detects a change in that unit or its dependancies.

Comment: Since you are the only answer and I do learn something from your post, I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: @Remy Certainly for Delphi, it behaves this way even with a brand new VCL Forms project