# Delphi XE5 recompiles each time I run a project. This occurs even when no changes are made

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I've scoured SO, blogs, and EDN looking for answers, but to no avail.  This cannot be intentional, I've even built the project outside of my regular code workspace to ensure there was no external changes being made, and the issue still occurs.

The closest similar issue I could find is below:

[in XE5 everytime I make a project it recompile everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531067/in-xe5-everytime-i-make-a-project-it-recompile-everything)

This even occurs with a new VCL form, with no changes made at all.  Each time I choose F9 to Run the project, I get a compiler dialog.  I recently migrated Delphi XE, which didn't have this issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This happens every time, even with Delphi 2007, even when there's no actual compiling happening. There's a check made on the project file, and then all dependencies are checked to see if anything changed. If the dialog is annoying, turn it off in Tools->Options->Environment Options by unchecking the "Show compiler progress" box. (The dialog shows just for a couple of seconds unless you've told it to stay visible.)

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you for your reply!  I understand and appreciate what the check is doing, but there are times where I will make no changes, and receive the dialog (albeit for about 10 seconds) and other times where the dialog doesn't even appear, and the application launches immediately, even with the "Show compiler progress" box checked.

Comment: How do we reproduce this?

Comment: You might get better responses on the Embarcadero forums, or contacting Embarcadero support. Depending on your luck, you may get your question closed as off-topic or too broad or whatever.

Comment: A variable-length delay between starting a compile/run and the application appearing can be caused by AV s/ware.  Also MalwareBytes, although not strictly AV, seems to cause similar.  This kind of s/ware often seems to "phone home" while it checks out a new app.

Comment: @Alex: Delphi, unlike most other compilers, actually generates an executable every time it runs your app. (With small applications, you often don't even notice because the compiler is so fast, especially when you don't show the compiler progress.) Any issue on your computer (other processes, pending disk I/O, the system file cache, etc.) that makes I/O slower will affect the compiler speed, meaning that with some projects compiling once will display the dialog (because the files aren't loaded into the cache) and compiling again won't. This has always been the case.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The simplest example I can think of is just creating a new VCL Forms application. File>New>VCL Forms Applcation>Run. Close the app> Click run again.  In XE, the app starts immediately, and XE5 it recompiles again.  I uploaded a video comparison of the two for sake of example here: http://youtu.be/WG7mO-lqOIw or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WG7mO-lqOIw  .  It's finished uploading although it may not be fully public as it's still processing.

Comment: @Ken On XE, F9 doesn't lead to compile if project up to date

Comment: @David: It does on projects of any significance in size, just like it does on D2007, XE2, XE5, and XE6. (Haven't done much with XE7 yet, so I don't have anything of any size to test with yet.)

Comment: @Ken I'm working on a brand new vcl forms app as per the asker's comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour appears to be by design. There's nothing wrong with your installations. All my Delphi installations from XE3 and later behave in the way you describe and show for your XE5 installation. All my XE2 and earlier installations behave in the manner you describe and show for your XE installation.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but doesn't it defeat the purpose of the dcu/up-to-date check if it always compiles regardless of whether it's changed?  I know for some it's an inconsequential problem,  but if I'm fixing a bug, it can cause a 2 minute test to take 10 minutes if I'm sitting there waiting for a recompile each time I run the application.

Comment: It only compiles the out of date units. When you do this on a big project, compilation takes a couple of seconds, time spent checking whether units are up to date or not.

Comment: Update: 
For anyone else that was as frustrated with this less that desirable "as designed" resolution, I've found a fix pack that has sped up the compiling process (at least for me) immensely.  Of course, as it has not been created by Embarcadero it is not a supported solution, but it sure as heck works for me! Link here: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/ Many thanks to Mr. Andreas Hausladen!

Comment: In Tokyo without IDE Fix Pack, disabling Error Insight _fixed_ the described problem.